# How to write a test for a method that updates a hash of hashes

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing a test for a method that tests the following method:

```
  def update rule_code, updated_rule
    list.select{ |rule|
      if rule[0] == rule_code
         rule[1] = updated_rule
       end
     }
  end
```

The test looks like:

```
  describe "#update" do
    it "updates a rule when given the rulecode and rule updates" do
      item_rule = double( {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50} )
      updated_rule = double( {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 4, new_item_price: 7.50} )
      rule_code = 1
      rules.add item_rule
      expect{rules.update(rule_code, updated_rule)}.to change{rules.list[rule_code]}.from(item_rule).to(updated_rule)
    end
  end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
1) Promotional_Rules#update updates a rule when given the rulecode and rule updates
   Failure/Error: rule[1] = updated_rule

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `[]=' for 1:Fixnum
   # ./lib/Promotional_Rules.rb:21:in `block in update'
   # ./lib/Promotional_Rules.rb:19:in `select'
   # ./lib/Promotional_Rules.rb:19:in `update'
   # ./spec/promotional_rules_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/promotional_rules_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test result isn't the issue as I am sure the final line of my test isn't correct. I am trying to test that in the following hash:

```
list = {1: {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50}, 2: {rule_type: "item", item_code: 2, number_of_items: 6, new_item_price: 9.50}
```

If I search for the original key "1" I can then update it with its corresponding pair. I also realize my method isn't correct either hence the test failure.

Comment: You have an undefined local variable `list`, unless it's an off-stage method that takes no arguments.

Comment: Please put in the effort to use correct grammar/spelling. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion board, it's a reference book, and grammar does matter.